# "Run Python File in Terminal" not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: I just clicked that button]

I just pressed that triangle to run the code. I want that button to work because I want to use the debug mode from that button. When I click it, it tries to run three times and it somehow got into anaconda. I checked Python default interpreter path in preferences>settings and it is set to C:\Users\ucanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe, not the anaconda one. I am pretty new to this and I do not know what is going on.

edit: It seems like it is running as WSL termial that is why it has name@LAPTOP-xxxx:/mnt/c/ in the front.

Comment: hi nomad, in the bottom left corner of VS code you should be able to see which python interpreter/virtual environment is running. You need to click on it and make that point to your anaconda python interpreter. It is usually located in C:\Users\<yourusername>\Anaconda3

Comment: I change it and it does not work. I think the problem is it is somehow running as WSL, that is why it is showing swan@LAPTOP-5SV7GFH0:/mnt/c/Users/ and that is causing the error.

Comment: yes it sounds a bit tricky running conda (for win?) in vs code via WSL :-) sure you don't need to install conda for linux in WSL, before using it with VS code?